# How to import wave library in python?

Tags: python, python-import

I tried to import in my code library wave (istalled by pip) like this:

```
import wave
```

And next what I used in my program is

```
raw = wave.open('file.wav', 'rb')
```

After run my program in console I had this wierd problem:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'open'
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What library is this? Clearly there is not `open` function in that library, but we cannot help you more than that.

Comment: Can you give us a bit more information? Specifically -- which version of Python are you using? And what is the whole error traceback? I can't replicate your problem on either Python 2.7.1 or Python 3.2.3

Comment: Do you mean the [standard library `wave`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html) that comes with Python? Check that you don't have a local file named `wave.py` first.

Comment: wave library is used to manipulate .wav files (standard library http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/wave.html)

Comment: `wave` comes with Python: http://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html It does have an `open` method on my system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably have a local file named `wave.py` that is being imported instead.

Check with:

```
import wave

print wave.__file__
```

and rename or delete that file.

Comment: Yes... My bad. I don't think in this way.

Comment: I was convinced this was not the solution... and then it was